# AVG Function in SQL

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

The two columns in the image are part of a table and I'm trying to get the AVG Sal depending on specific date. For example, the Avg sal for 1981. Because of the date, I can't get it. How do I do this? Thanks!

[2 Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDMYQ.png)

Comment: I got this data from a little online course I'm taking but I was just thinking that in the real world, the hiredate data should be better structured and have 3 different columns 1) year 2) month and 3) day so it'd very simply to take the AVG sal per year_hiredate. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: Not at all.  Storing month and year in separate columns is generally not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this option:

```
SELECT AVG(SAL) AS AVG_SAL
FROM yourTable
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE) = 1981;
```

More generally, to find averages for all years:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE) AS HIRE_YEAR,
    AVG(SAL) AS AVG_SAL
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE);
```

Comment: thanks so much for the tip and the answer! It works pretty well. I just learned a new command (EXTRACT). I'll read more about it tomorrow. Hopefully they teach it by the end of my little course as it looks very helpful to break down dates, times and so on. Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT AVG(SAL)
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE HIREDATE BETWEEN '1/1/1981' AND '12/31/1981'
```

Here we're using the BETWEEN operator which is pretty handy in SQL and is not limited to dates. You might also look through the Oracle documentation for some handy date and time functions.

Comment: I think you would need `BETWEEN DATE '1981-01-01' AND DATE '1981-12-31'`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen makes a good point for date handling. For U.S., MM/DD/YY is a common date format, but isn't used everywhere in the world. 'YY-MM-DD' is a more international format and its less ambiguous (at least for me) about which field is month and which is year. The thing I don't know is what formats Oracle can handle. In the picture of the table in the OP the format is the same I used in my answer.

Comment: @bfris Interesting! I kind of tried that one before posting (but I added a having clause after the where clause --I'm new to this world, but didn't decide to try without the having clause). That one worked too! Thanks!!